# how to set mod_pagespeed to work on all pages

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, mod-pagespeed

I've been trying with [mod_pagespeed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/download.html) and would like to know if anyone know's how I can add a rule to my `httpd.conf` that would **automatically add all current virtual hosts to the list of running domains**:

```
ModPagepeedDomain http://vhost1.com
ModPagepeedDomain http://vhost2.com
ModPagepeedDomain http://vhost3.com
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please don't ask questions with a single, never-before-seen tag. That defeats the point of the tag system.

Comment: @skaffman I stand corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ModPagespeedDomain` seems to accept wildcards. From [here](https://gist.github.com/662217):

```
# Wildcards (* and ?) are allowed in the domain specification. Be
# careful when using them as if you rewrite domains that do not
# send you traffic, then the site receiving the traffic will not
# know how to serve the rewritten content.

ModPagespeedDomain *
```

Place this in the conf file proper, outside any vhosts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use wildcards, but please don't use ModPagespeedDomain * unless you can actually control the whole web!

This declaration decides which resources to rewrite and which not to. It is a contract saying that all servers matching the pattern will have mod_pagespeed installed!

Please use something like:

```
ModPagespeedDomain vhost?.com
```

Unless you are actually behind a rewriting proxy that can rewrite from any domain.

Also, you can contact us at mod-pagespeed-discuss@googlegroups.com and list issues at http://code.google.com/p/modpagespeed/issues/list